# build openwrt on mac os x failed, how to fix it?

Tags: macos, openwrt

```
export MAKEFLAGS= ;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C /Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/build_dir/host/bc-1.06.95 install
Making install in lib
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in bc
test -z "/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/bin" || /Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/build_dir/host/bc-1.06.95/install-sh -d "/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/bin"
  /Users/zhushajun/ctags/install -c 'bc' '/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/bin/bc'
/bin/bash: /Users/zhushajun/ctags/install: Permission denied
make[6]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[5]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/stamp/.bc_installed] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/tools/bc'
make[2]: *** [tools/bc/install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk'
make[1]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk/staging_dir/target-mipsel_24kec+dsp_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.tools_install_yynyynynynyyyyyyyyyynyyyyyyyynyyyynnyyynnyynnnyyyy] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/trunk'
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

sorry for my poor English.
these are the output info,"make V=s" not work and "sudo make V=s" neither,somebody would help me?thanks